# Google SignUp/Login using PHP backend and client as web and android

Tags: php, android, google-api-php-client, restangular, cartalyst-sentinel

So I am trying to implement Google Login in my application. On the client side I have an android App and a web app which interact with the restful API server in PHP (Cartalyst Sentinel 2.0 for authentication).

I am facing multiple issues.

1. **REDIRECT URI**

   `//setting up google api client
     $client = new Google_Client();
     $client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID_WEB);
     $client->setClientSecret($CLIENT_SECRET_WEB);
     $client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
     $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));`

   To instantiate the client I need to provide redirect Uri. Now in the case of the client being webApp there seems to be no issue as I am providing the same redirect URI at the client and server end. But when it comes to android there is no REDIRECT URI. I read somewhere that 'postmessage' as redirect uri works but didn't for me. Without the redirect URI the client throws error of **"invalid json token"**

Any help on this ?

2. **cartalyst_sentinel** cookie as **null** in the requests from web client.

There seemes to be no issue in case of normal login(api.domain.xyz/login) through credentials. But when at the server end I login the client from a different route(api.domain.xyz/blabla/google/login) the value for the cartalyst_sentinel cookie goes null even though the set cookie headers were sent as response headers.
[image]
Set-Cookie header being sent(There are two, which worries me but it works this way as well in case of native login)

[image]
The cookie is becoming null in the requests which follow after login

I have read a lot by now about these issues and have tried n number of methods but none seem to be working.

There were only two things that seemed a bit valid.

- The case of redirect URI can be sorted out by instantiating the google api client with config file(google json or developer key maybe).
- The case of missing cookie is due to cross domain cookies or maybe due to login being done through a nested route(sounds silly I know, but found somewhere in google).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please share an answer if you have figured this out. I dont know what to search to get a result.